# Get Reports from SAP BO server to Shared drive via SSIS

Tags: ssis, crystal-reports, business-objects

I have a requirement to get copies of reports in SAP BO server and drop them in a Shared drive via SSIS.
I have no idea on the BO server side ,Is this possible? If yes, kindly guide me on this.

TIA :)

- Aiswarya

Answer (score 0):

Sure - that's basic scheduling functionality.  You just have to schedule it to save to the designated UNC path.